# Connect to Kakfka broker with SASL_PLAINTEXT in docker-compose (binami/kafka)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am implementing username/password in Kafka.

When I tried with `PLAINTEXT` works as expected, but when I implement `SASL_PLAINTEXT` I can't connect.

This is my docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    zookeeper:
      container_name: zookeeper
      image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
      ports:
        - 2181:2181
      environment:
        - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    kafka4userpass: 
      container_name: kafka4userpass
      image: bitnami/kafka:latest
      ports:
        - '9096:9096'
      environment:
        - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=4
        - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
        - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PROTOCOL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
        - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
        - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
        - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9096
        - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka4userpass:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9096
        - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
        - KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS=kafkauser
        - KAFKA_CLIENT_PASSWORDS=kafkapassword
      volumes:
        - './test/docker-compose/kafka_jaas.conf:/opt/bitnami/kafka/conf/kafka_jaas.conf:ro'
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
    kafdrop:
      container_name: kafdrop
      image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
      restart: "no"
      ports:
        - "9000:9000"
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "CLIENT://kafka1:9092,CLIENT://kafka2:9092,CLIENT://kafka3:9092,CLIENT://kafka4userpass:9092"
        JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M -Xss180K -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -noverify"
      depends_on:
        #- "kafka1"
        #- "kafka2"
        #- "kafka3"
        - "kafka4userpass"
```

The one I have the issue with is `kafka4userpass`.

and this is my `kafka_jass.conf`

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="kafkauser"
    password="kafkapassword";
};


Client {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.PlainLoginModule required
    username="kafkauser"
    password="kafkapassword";
};
```

I can see the broker in Kafdrop, but I cannot connect.

I tried to use `Offset explorer 2.1` setting their jass config section to : `org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="kafkauser" password="kafkapassword";`

- note: I also changed the mechanism to `PLAIN`

But I am getting `Invalid Username or password`.

Any idea which file I am missing or which configuration do I have wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from configuration

KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PROTOCOL SASL_PLAINTEXT

`KafkaServer {  
    
     org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    user_kafkauser="kafkapassword";
    };`

Notice user_kafkauser

Comment: no luck, exact same result: `INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=4] Failed authentication with /192.168.112.1 (Authentication failed: Invalid username or password) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)`

Comment: Remove this as well "Client" section from jaas, and check edited answer

Comment: did it already :( . I have only the `KafkaServer ` and `KafkaClient` and the `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PROTOCOL ` its gone

Comment: Added user_kafkauser into KafkaServer?

Comment: oh I didnt saw that Edit, my bad, yes, now "it worked"; There is another error but that means progress, thanks. :)

Comment: For your serting you dont need KafkaClient in jaas , remove it and check it is still "working"

Comment: You can also remove user,password from server - check updates KafkaServer